# How can I have more space between line number and code?

Tags: line-numbers

Bascially, I want to increase the space between line number and code. Other line number plugin is also acceptable.

From this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. See [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7893390/4194289).

Comment: not really possible, I made a [patch](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-mq-patches/blob/1177c4535380df983a2cb58720dbeeaee5d498fe/leftmargin) to add a 'leftmargin' option

Answer (score 1):

The option `numberwidth` changes the width of the number gutter.
E.g.
`set numberwidth=10`

Answer (score 0):

It works (in the 'vim terminal') ...like
`%left 5`
`%` : whole document
`left`: distance between linenrs and code
`0 till infinitiy' : how many columns (=space of a monospace character) to go to the left

Comment: Note that this actually re-justifies the code (the purpose of the left command). I think the OP was looking for more of a visual effect that didn’t modify the code.